# Slow resume from sleep

Tags: release-loki, suspend

When I open my computer, elementary OS Loki takes about 10-15 seconds to resume from sleep. The screen is initially off. After a second or two, the backlight turns on but the screen is still black for a while before the login screen appears.

Resuming from sleep took just a few seconds on eOS Freya. I'm running a Dell XPS 13 from 2015.

Any thoughts on how I might speed up the process of resuming from sleep? Thanks!

Comment: I have a similar problem sometimes, specifically, when initially logging in sometimes it takes upwards of a minute for the panel and dock to show up. Also, when shutting down there's a similar lag.

Comment: I may confirm this happening on my Acer F555L Laptop. It takes around 15-25 seconds to get to the login screen.

Comment: I have a similar issue. guest session works fine.

Comment: 2019 and I'm still having this issue with ElementaryOS :|

Answer (score -1):

you may try to run this on terminal: 
sudo systemctl disable cups-browsed

Comment: This answer would be more helpful if it elaborated on why you suggest this solution

Comment: Please specify what this does and what will happen when you disable it.