# elementary os rouse with slow speed

Tags: suspend

Dose any body knows how to speed it up?

```
OS:
   elementary OS 5.1.3 Hera
   uilt on Ubuntu 18.04.3 LTS
   Linux 5.3.0-28-generic
   GTK 3.22.30
hardware:
   Quad-Core Intel Core i7-8565U @ 1.80GHz
   16.2GB memory
   686GB storage (NVMe SSD)
```

Comment: Hi what does 'rouse' mean please? Wake from sleep/suspend? How long (in seconds or minutes) does it actually take? And what kind of hardware is this running on please?

Comment: Thans for your reply, I've updated the description, added the hadware specs. And yes, rouse means : > Wake from sleep/suspend. It takes 4~5 seconds to wake from sleep.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For what it's worth I think this behavior may be related to Ubuntu 18.04.

Looks like the same problem was reported [here](https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/questions/7852/slow-resume-from-sleep?rq=1)

For what it's worth, your system isn't actually sleeping, it's suspending. I'd love to be told otherwise but it seems to me like Elementary doesn't actually properly support sleep but instead suspends your laptop.